# Parsing JSON from an API Result

Tags: json, parsing, rust, serde-json

I'm using RUST and Reqwest to call the following Response from an API:

Shell:

```
Ok("{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T12:50:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":68.0464}\n"{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T12:55:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":67.4408}\n
{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:00:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":87.2918}\n
{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:05:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":98.1406}\n
{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:10:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":87.4789}\n
{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:15:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":90.2434}\n
{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:20:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":89.8617}\n
{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:25:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":97.2639}\n
{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:30:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":100.493}\n
{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:35:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":93.7984}\n
{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:40:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":85.1182}\n
{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:45:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":91.4173}\n\n",
)
```

I want to parse this output and only print the 'RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0' value in the first array (the figure in **BOLD** below) that I recieve from the call:

Ok("{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T12:50:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":**68.0464**}\n"
...

I'm still very new to RUST and trying to work out how I should best achieve this.
Could anyone in the community here help with some recommendations/help.

**What have I tried:**

I've been working with the following code:

```
extern crate serde_json;

use serde_json::Value;

fn main() {
    let data: Value = serde_json::from_str(
//          Ok(
           "{\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T12:50:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":68.0464}\n"
//           {\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T12:55:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":67.4408}\n
//            {\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:00:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":87.2918}\n
//            {\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:05:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":98.1406}\n
//            {\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:10:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":87.4789}\n
//            {\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:15:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":90.2434}\n
//            {\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:20:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":89.8617}\n
//            {\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:25:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":97.2639}\n
//            {\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:30:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":100.493}\n
//            {\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:35:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":93.7984}\n
//            {\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:40:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":85.1182}\n
//            {\"SETTLEMENTDATE\":\"2019-10-24T13:45:00Z\",\"REGIONID\":\"VIC1\",\"RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0\":91.4173}\n\n",
//            )
    )
    .unwrap();



    println!("data: {:?}", data);
    let obj = data.as_object().unwrap();
    let RRP = obj.get("RRP.DISPATCHPRICE0").unwrap();

    println!("Value: {}", RRP);
}
```

The above prints out the Number I want and works nicely but I can't get it to work when I comment in the rest of the 'Response'.

Please help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string as a whole is not valid JSON because it contains more than one object. You can get around it by using a [`StreamDeserializer`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/struct.StreamDeserializer.html) to extract the objects one by one:

```
for value in Deserializer::from_str (data).into_iter::<Value>() {
    println!("value: {:?}", value.unwrap());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=4e588b5b05b42341b8a3185052f1b659)